# Grails plugin installation

Tags: maven, grails, gradle

I am having some problem in grails plugin installation maybe i am not installing it the expected way but on every grails plugin repo on grails plugin page there are two things, they say to install a plugin in grails 
For any plugin:

First one is  `compile ":jaxrs:0.8"`
 

 and second one is  :`grails install-plugin jaxrs`

My question is do i need to follow both step in order?  are they complimentary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need both steps. Just add the line

```
compile ":jaxrs:0.8"
```

to BuildConfig.groovy and run grails app.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: No, you do not need to do both. Older versions of Grails (pre 2.x) preferred the install-plugins method to install plugins over the modification of your grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy. I would suggest becoming accustom to modifying your BuildConfig.groovy as your process to installing plugins.